# youtube-dl download location

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I am trying to save youtube videos as MP3's in my downloads folder. However, this ends up saving files in the same directory as youtube-dl.

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality=320k 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID 
--output C:/Users/Josue/Downloads/%(title)s.%(ext)s
```

I wanted the videos to save at:

`C:/Users/Josue/Downloads/videotitle.mp3`

however, they are saving as:

`C:/youtube-dl/videotitle-videoID.mp3`

Am I doing something incorrectly? I tried reading the documentation on [Github](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl), but I was still a bit confused.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed to put the options in the following order:

```
youtube-dl --output C:/Users/Josue/Downloads/%(title)s.%(ext)s
 --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 
 --audio-quality=320k https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID
```

Comment: The order of options is ignored by youtube-dl.

Comment: @phihag, not really; the URL(s) must come after the options. In his original post, he was putting the output after the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cd C:\Users\Josue\Downloads
C:\youtube-dl\youtube-dl --etc
```

Comment: Or better, use `pushd` and `popd`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (for a unix environment):

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video_id> --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o '/var/www/html/audio/%(id)s.%(ext)s'
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows - double %

`%%(title)s.%%(ext)s`

Answer (score 0):

you can create a configuration file to do this for you , just add those lines to your config file (if you have one, if not create it in C:/Users/Josue youtube-dl.conf) `-o C:/Users/Josue/Downloads/%(title)s.%(ext)s` .
[Link](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#configuration) for details